# Assign a serial number when quantity is more than one

Tags: python, django

I have a model in which a unique serial number is generated, and there is a quantity field in which the user can select how many parts they'd like made. Think of it like a shopping order. I'd like that if the user selects a quantity of more than one, a serial number be assigned to each individual part.
Models:

```
from __future__ import unicode_literals
from tande.models import Project, Person
from django.db import models
from django.utils import timezone
from django.utils.text import slugify
from django.core.exceptions import NON_FIELD_ERRORS, ValidationError
from django.utils.translation import ugettext_lazy as _
from django.core.urlresolvers import reverse
from django.db.models.signals import pre_save
from django.conf import settings

# Create your models here.
class buildrisk(models.Model):
    risk = models.CharField(max_length=20, default = 'Select Risk')
    def __unicode__ (self):
            return self.risk

class sens(models.Model):
    sens = models.CharField(max_length=20, default = 'Select Sensitivity')
    def __unicode__ (self):
            return self.sens

class MOI(models.Model):
    method = models.CharField(max_length=20, default = 'Select Method')
    def __unicode__ (self):
            return self.method

def number():
    no = PartRequest.objects.count()
    if no == None:
        return "PR00001"
    else:
        return "PR00" + str(no + 100)

def snumber():
    no = PartRequest.objects.count()
    add = sum(map(int, str(no)))
    if no == None:
        return "SN00001"
    else:
        return "SN00" + str(no + 100 + add)
    # while n:
    #   sn, n = sn + n % 10, n // 10
    # return sn

class PartRequest(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, default=1)
    part_request_number = models.CharField(_('Part Request Number'),max_length=10, default = number)
    serialnumber = models.CharField(_('Serial Number'),max_length=10, default= snumber)
    project_manager = models.ForeignKey(Person, related_name = 'Manager', null = True)
    requester = models.ForeignKey(Person, related_name = 'Requester', null = True)  #drop down
    project_id = models.ForeignKey(Project, related_name = 'Project', null=True)
    ordernumber = models.PositiveIntegerField(_('Order Number'), default=0)
    description = models.CharField(_('Description'), max_length=500)
    quantityrequired = models.PositiveIntegerField(_('Quantity'), default=0)
    sensitivity = models.ForeignKey(sens, related_name='sensitivity', null=True) #drop down
    identification_method = models.ForeignKey(MOI, related_name= 'MOI', null=True)
    build_risk = models.ForeignKey(buildrisk, related_name= 'Risk', null=True)
    daterequired = models.DateField(_('Date Required'), default = '04/08/16')
    slug = models.SlugField(unique=True, null=True)
    def __str__(self):
        return unicode(self.requester)

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return "/buildpage/%s/" %(self.slug)
#return ("buildpage:page3", kwargs = {"slug": self.slug})

def create_slug(instance, new_slug=None):
    slug = slugify(instance.part_request_number)
    if new_slug is not None:
        slug = new_slug
    qs = PartRequest.objects.filter(slug=slug).order_by("-id")
    exists = qs.exists()
    if exists:
        new_slug = "%s-%s" %(slug, qs.first().id)
        return create_slug(instance, new_slug=new_slug)
    return slug

def pre_save_receiver(sender, instance, *args, **kwargs):
    if not instance.slug:
        instance.slug = create_slug(instance)
pre_save.connect(pre_save_receiver, sender = PartRequest)
```

Views:

```
from django.shortcuts import render, get_object_or_404, redirect, get_object_or_404
from django.contrib import messages
from django.http import HttpResponse, Http404, HttpResponseRedirect
from django.template import RequestContext, loader
from django.contrib.auth.decorators import login_required
from .forms import PartRequestForm
from .models import PartRequest
from tande.models import Project, Person

 # Create your views here.
@login_required
def home(request):
    latest_project_list = Project.objects.all()
    context = {'latest_project_list': latest_project_list}
    return render(request, 'buildpage/home.html', context)

def partrequestinfo(request):
    if not request.user.is_staff or not request.user.is_superuser:
        raise Http404
    req_form = PartRequestForm(request.POST or None, request.FILES or None)
    if req_form.is_valid():
            instance = req_form.save(commit=False)
            instance.user = request.user
            print request.POST
            print req_form.cleaned_data.get("requester")
            print instance
            instance.save()
            messages.success(request, "Successfully Created")
            return HttpResponseRedirect(instance.get_absolute_url())
    else: 
        context = {
                "req_form": req_form
        }
    return render(request, "buildpage/partrequestinfo.html", context)

def partrequestdetail(request, slug=None):
    print "in partrequestdetail function"
    instance = get_object_or_404(PartRequest, slug=slug)
    context = {
        "project_id": instance.project_id,
        "instance": instance,
    }
    return render(request, 'buildpage/partrequestdetail.html', context)

def partrequestupdate(request, slug=None):
    if not request.user.is_staff or not request.user.is_superuser:
        raise Http404
    instance = get_object_or_404(PartRequest, slug=slug)
    req_form = PartRequestForm(request.POST or None, request.FILES or None, instance=instance)
    if req_form.is_valid():
            instance = req_form.save(commit=False)
            print request.POST
            print req_form.cleaned_data.get("requester")
            print instance
            instance.save()
            messages.success(request, "Saved")
            return HttpResponseRedirect(instance.get_absolute_url())
    context = {
        "project_id": instance.project_id,
        "instance": instance,
        "req_form": req_form,
    }
    return render(request, 'buildpage/partrequestinfo.html', context)

def partrequestdelete(request, slug=None):
    if not request.user.is_staff or not request.user.is_superuser:
        raise Http404
    instance = get_object_or_404(PartRequest, slug=slug)
    messages.success(request, "Successfully Deleted")
    return redirect("buildpage:home")

def preparebuildlist(request, slug=None):

    return render(request, 'buildpage/preparebuildlist.html')
```

Comment: What is your actual question? Have you already designed a model for it?

Comment: Yep, everythings been designed, serial numbers are being generated for each part request, what I need is that if more than a quantity of more than one is selected, each one gets a different serial number. I'll add my models and views.

Answer (score 0):

I can't really understand your models, but I think what you need (if you don't already have it) is a `Part` model. Have one field in the `Part` model be the serial number of the part, which can be automatically generated if you want, and so when a user requests X number of parts you can just create and save X `Part` objects.